# Subtracting average values from columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am making a code in python with pandas dataframe that averages values in hourly data from 12am-3am for a month and then subtracts that monthly average from each column.  The code reads the data from a csv file.

**Sample of data**

```
DateTime         C1      C2      C3      C4      C5      V
11/1/2014 0:00  1.12    0.96    1.11    0.95    0.93    4.06
11/1/2014 1:00  1.12    0.96    1.11    0.95    0.93    4.06
11/1/2014 2:00  1.12    0.95    1.11    0.95    0.93    4.06
11/1/2014 3:00  1.12    0.95    1.11    0.95    0.93    4.06
11/1/2014 4:00  1.12    0.95    1.11    0.95    0.93    4.06
11/1/2014 5:00  1.12    0.95    1.11    0.95    0.93    4.06
11/1/2014 6:00  1.12    0.95    1.11    0.96    0.93    5.24
11/1/2014 7:00  1.14    0.96    1.12    0.98    0.95    498.64
11/1/2014 8:00  1.22    1.04    1.20    1.05    1.02    623.51
11/1/2014 9:00  1.46    1.28    1.43    1.27    1.25    641.80
```

So the code I am using to get the average is

```
df.ix[:,1:5].between_time('0:00', '3:00').resample('1M').mean()
```

This code gives me the average from 12-3am for the month for columns 1-5.  Now how can I subtract those average values from each value in columns 1-5?

Comment: ```df.ix[:, 1:5] = df.ix[:, 1:5] - your_res.values``` should do.

Comment: my data is saved as the variable df.  When I try to set something up like (df - df.ix[:, 1:5]) I get a bunch of NaN values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
month_av = df.ix[:,1:5].between_time('0:00', '3:00').resample('1M').mean()
df.ix[:, 1:5] = df.ix[:, 1:5] - month_av.values
```

Comment: I think this works.  How can I append those values into the csv file to replace the other values?

Comment: Once your pandas data frame looks how you want it, you can just do df.to_csv(filename) just know that this will overwrite the old csv if you use the same filename

Comment: The only issue with this is when I save it to a csv it deletes the columns I didn't do the subtraction on.  How can I keep those columns in the data while still subtracting the other ones?

Comment: Can you paste your whole code? I'm not sure exactly what you're doing. My only thought is you might be doing df = df.ix[:, 1:5] - month_av.values instead of df.ix[:, 1:5] = df.ix[:, 1:5] - month_av.values

Comment: You are correct that is what I was doing.  Thank you for the help!